# Safari shows submit button background color whitish

Tags: html, css, safari

I am facing strange issue when a html button is viewed in safari mobile browsers, instead of appearing red, it appears whitewashed.

[image]

It should appear like this in red

[image]

The css styles applied

```
input[type="submit"] {
    background: #cc0000 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid darkred !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    padding: 15px 20px !important;
}
```

How to fix?

Comment: Looks like you haven't reset the default styles in Safari Mobile...those buttons look **nothing** alike. There's more than just a difference in background color.

Comment: Just a guess, but could it be this: `-webkit-appearance: none;`